# escapping characters of sed inside a script

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to use sed inside a bash script to get only hidden values

```
sed -n 's/.*<INPUT NAME="res_encab" TYPE=HIDDEN VALUE="\(.*\)>.*/\1/ip;T;q'
```

But i cant get the escape the pattern correctly

inside my script i have this

```
echo $var | sed -n "s/.*<INPUT NAME=\"res_encab\" TYPE=HIDDEN VALUE=\"\(.*\)>.*/\1/ip;T;q"
```

But when i run the script i get

```
bla bla bla bla"> <INPUT NAME="Res_numero" TYPE=hidden VALUE="bla blaa...
```

insted of

```
bla bla bla bla
```

any sugestion?

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern might be too strict or just plain incorrect. It's good to start with something simple that works but maybe not strict enough, like this:

```
var='<INPUT NAME="Res_numero" TYPE=hidden VALUE="bla as"asdsad>'
echo "$var" | sed -ne 's/.*VALUE="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p'
```

Get a simple proof of concept working, then gradually make it more and more strict as necessary, testing at every step if your expression is still working or not.